# Add time to date time in php

Tags: php

The date and time format I have is:

Example 1:

```
$dateTime = 2016-09-08 21:00; //(year-month-day hour:minute)
$interval = 04:00; //(hour:minute)
$outputShouldBe = 2016-09-09 01:00;
```

Example 2:

```
$dateTime = 2016-09-08 21:00; //(year-month-day hour:minute)
$interval = 01:40; //(hour:minute)
$outputShouldBe = 2016-09-08 22:40;
```

Comment: what code have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
$dateTime = '2016-09-08 21:00';
echo date( "Y-m-d h:i", strtotime( "2016-09-08 21:00 +4 hours" ) ); 
echo date( "Y-m-d H:i", strtotime( "2016-09-08 21:00 +1 hours 40 minutes" ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) to archieve your task. The code can be made shorter if you desire. But it is more readable like that.

```
$dt = new Datetime('2016-09-08 21:00');
$interval = new DateInterval('PT4H');
$dt->add($interval);

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i');


$dt = new Datetime('2016-09-08 21:00');
$interval = new DateInterval('PT1H40M');
$dt->add($interval);

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $dateTime = '2016-09-08 21:00';
    $intervalhr = 4;
    $intervalmin= 0;
    //display the converted time
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('+'.$intervalhr .' hour ',strtotime($dateTime)));
```

you can do by giving hour in integer and same for minutes